# iOS Swift, Passing a variable from ViewController to a class in the same ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController (A), which takes the output (quantity) of a swift class "QuantityMatrix  { var qMatrix = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]] // returns quantity}" and performs some action.

The code works fine if I provide the qMatrix to the RateMatrix Class. But, now I want to generate the variable qMatrix from other View Controller (B) and use it in the QuantityMatrix class.

I am not getting how to pass the qMatrix from the View Controller (B). can anyone help?

ex:

```
Class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
var qMatrix = QuantityMatrix() 

// uses the 'quantity' returned from QuantityMatrix class to perform some action
}

Class QuantityMatrix {
var qMatrix:[[String]] = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]]
//
.
.
return quantity
}
```

The above works fine, but now instead of directly using the [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]] values, I am generating these values from another viewcontroller (B). For this, I need to pass the variable generated in B controller to QuantityMatrix. Can anyone tell how?

I am new. So please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Classes do not return values, methods do.

Comment: @dallen Sorry. The code uses get{} inside QuantityMatrix which returns. So can you help me?

Comment: get{} needs to be inside a computed property

Comment: @dallen I am using this to be exact. http://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/swift-programming-101-advanced-collections-1

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a reference from from View Controller A to View Controller B, then it can simply ask for the values by calling a func.

The best place to do this is often in prepareForSegue, though it will depend on how you're opening the views.

Comment: I am currently using the prepareForSegue to pass the new generated values for qMatrix from VC B to VC A. But the problem is, qMatrix is in Class QuantityMatrix() not in VC A. So when I try to use the new generated quantity variable (passed from B to A using the segue) it gives me an error "does not have a member named..". I also tried putting the Class QuantityMatrix inside the VCA class. Still it gives me an error "does not have a member named...".

Comment: Then you need to create the QuantityMatrix class at the global level, simply create a new file and put the class definition in that, this way both VCs can access it.

Comment: I think I am not able to explain my problem clearly. Can you please check this code? https://github.com/nitin1518/dateBarRate. I want to replace variable qMatrix in QuantityMatrix.swift with this new variable created in dataViewController.swift. I would really appreciate if you could help me in this. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Is it difficult? I really want to do this if someone can help me get this working. Also, I checked about declaring the variable globally and found that it will cause bugs and is not a good code practice. Is it?. So, will it be good to save the variable on device using code data and retrieve from there?